# Setting a color from spectrum to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, spectrum

I am having a difficult time trying to figure out how to set a color I choose from spectrum to another div. My HTML is like this:

```
<h2>Full Example</h2>
<input type='text' id="full"/>

<div class="outside-preview">

</div>
<div id="inside-preview">

</div>
```

The input is the spectrum and it changes the small box color. This is all standard to the plugin. I am wanting to set that same color to one of the boxes (inside-preview or outside-preview) as well.

Does anyone see what I have to do?

[Click to see it in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/way4LmbL/)

[Here is the github page](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their documentation you can use the [`change`-function](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#events-change) for that:

```
change: function(color) {
    $('.outside-preview').css('background-color',  color.toHexString())
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/way4LmbL/1/)

---

To set the backgroundcolor for the corresponding `div` with multiple colorpickers you can use something like this:

```
var eq =  $(this).index('.colorpicker');
$('.container').eq(eq).css('background-color', color.toHexString());
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/way4LmbL/5/)

Comment: Thanks! Do you see how I could have two inputs with different colors? I tried adding another input with a name and it did nothing to help. This example doesn't have your answer as I kind of figured it out on my own, but your solution is better. https://jsfiddle.net/way4LmbL/2/

Comment: see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/way4LmbL/3/) example. Set up 2 colopickers and select the respective div to set the background.

Comment: Gotcha! I see $("#full").spectrum({` was holding me back too. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Sorry for having to ask you something again, but why won't the inputs work when brought outside the div? I am wanting the inputs to be above and not inside the div, due to future positioning. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/way4LmbL/4/

Comment: @Becky thats because how the [dom-traversing](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/) works with `nextAll()`, for your layout you could using something like this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/way4LmbL/5/)

Comment: Why if I change the inputs around won't the system recognize the inner input first? I am confused on this.. https://jsfiddle.net/way4LmbL/8/